# HDF + pandas: how can I use a where mask with multindex?

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5, pyhdf

I would like to select from a HUGE hdf5 a subset of the data, day by day. It would be perfect to use a [where mask](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#advanced-queries), but I can't make it work with a multiindex (since I have to have a where with two conditions). can't use a where mask with a multiindex:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = ('A', 'B')
i = (0, 1, 2)
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(itertools.product(a, i)),
                            names=('Alpha', 'Int'))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(idx), 7), index=idx,
              columns=('I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII'))
```

[image]

Ok, now I put it in a hdf store

```
from pandas.io.pytables import HDFStore
store =HDFStore('cancella.h5', 'w')
store.append('df_mask',df)
```

But if I read it again I have

```
c = store.select_column('df_mask','index')
print c
```

this index which is WRONG.

```
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
dtype: int64
```

So I can't use the [where mask](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#advanced-queries). Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because pandas might `reset_index` before putting table into `HDF5` (reason might be that it tries to avoid any potential duplicated index, which is allowed in dataframe but very bad for database), and use the integer auto-incremented primary key as the index in `HDF5` table. So the code you wrote in the post selects these auto-incremented primary key.

There might be some other more elegant approaches, but I found the following work. (a consequence if pandas indeed `reset_index`, so now that multi-level index becomes columns...)

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = ('A', 'B')
i = (0, 1, 2)
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(itertools.product(a, i)),
                            names=('Alpha', 'Int'))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(idx), 7), index=idx,
              columns=('I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'VI', 'VII'))
print(df)

store = pd.HDFStore('/home/Jian/Downloads/temp.h5')
store.append('df_mask',df)

store.select('df_mask', columns=['Alpha','Int'])
```

[image]

Comment: I have to use a where mask, so I can't just select two columns as you do in the last line. Moreover, pandas doesn't reset_index, because the DataFrame is correct when I read it with read_hdf.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Pandas [`to_hdf`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_hdf.html) (after installing pytables)?

```
df.to_hdf('/Users/Alexander/Downloads/hdf.h5', key='data', format='t')

>>> pd.read_hdf('/Users/Alexander/Downloads/hdf.h5', 'data', columns='index')
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(A, 0), (A, 1), (A, 2), (B, 0), (B, 1), (B, 2)]
```

Choosing the format='t' option:

> "Write as a PyTables Table structure which may perform worse but allow
>   more flexible operations like searching / selecting subsets of the
>   data"

This documentation provides details of selecting data with a [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#advanced-queries) mask.

Comment: It doesn't help. to_hdf is just a wrapper :)

Answer (score 0):

This may be orthogonal to your question, but I don't see a column or an index in your DataFrame called 'index' so I don't know what you're actually selecting with

```
c = store.select_column('df_mask','index')
```

I've always used the `read_hdf` wrapper to deal with PyTables and have found it very flexible. The syntax for it is exceedingly flexible, e.g.

```
c = pd.read_hdf('/home/Jian/Downloads/temp.h5', 'df_mask', where="Alpha='A' | Alpha='B' & Int=0")
```

There's a firm limit to the number of conditions in your where clause, but if I've read your question correctly, that'd be a second order issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

In current pandas version 0.24.2, you may use direct querying without intermediate MultiIndex retrieval:

```py
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([('A', 'B'), range(3)], names=('Alpha', 'Int'))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(idx), 3), index=idx,
                  columns=('I', 'II', 'III'))
df

>>>                    I           II         III
>>> Alpha   Int             
>>>     A   0    0.547846   -1.630704    0.456686
>>>         1   -0.057442   -0.232721    0.349548
>>>         2    1.495230    0.661166    1.309862
>>>     B   0    2.116818    0.477923   -0.252352
>>>         1    1.001081    2.578723   -0.040782
>>>         2   -1.286964    0.357969    0.002976
```

Just use built-in `where` mask:

```py
with pd.HDFStore('test.h5') as store:
    store.put('df_mask', df, format='t')
    store.select('df_mask', where = 'Alpha = A & Int in [0,2]')

>>>                         I          II        III
>>> Alpha   Int             
>>>     A     0      0.621453   -1.757883   0.494433
>>>           2     -0.689012   -1.254884   0.655424
```

For different functions allowed in where mask visit [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#querying).

But if your desired filters are very complicated and you want to retrieve MultiIndex and build mask 'by hands', you may select it like [so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56403075/10711194):

```py
with pd.HDFStore('test.h5') as store:
    store.select('df_mask', columns=['index'])

>>> Alpha   Int
>>>     A     0
>>>           1
>>>           2
>>>     B     0
>>>           1
>>>           2
```