# How to retrieve pandas df multiindex from HDFStore?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hdf5, multi-index

If DataFrame with simple index is the case, one may retrieve index from HDFStore as follows:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 3), index=list('yz'), columns=list('abc'))
df

>>>      a          b           c
>>> y   -0.181063   1.919440    1.550992
>>> z   -0.701797   1.917156    0.645707
```

```py
with pd.HDFStore('test.h5') as store:
    store.put('df', df, format='t')
    store.select_column('df', 'index')

>>> 0    y
>>> 1    z
>>> Name: index, dtype: object
```

As stated in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#select-a-single-column).

But in case with MultiIndex such trick doesn't work:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 3),
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(0,'y'), (1, 'z')], names=['lvl0', 'lvl1']),
                  columns=list('abc'))
df

>>>                 a           b           c
>>> lvl0    lvl1            
>>>    0       y    -0.871125   0.001773     0.618647
>>>    1       z     1.001547   1.132322    -0.215681
```

More precisely it returns *wrong* index:

```py
with pd.HDFStore('test.h5') as store:
    store.put('df', df, format='t')
    store.select_column('df', 'index')

>>> 0    0
>>> 1    1
>>> Name: index, dtype: int64
```

How to retrieve correct DataFrame MultiIndex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One may use `select` with `columns=['index']` parameter specified:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2, 3),
                  index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(0,'y'), (1, 'z')], names=['lvl0', 'lvl1']),
                  columns=list('abc'))
df

>>>                 a           b           c
>>> lvl0    lvl1            
>>>    0       y    -0.871125   0.001773     0.618647
>>>    1       z     1.001547   1.132322    -0.215681
```

```py
with pd.HDFStore('test.h5') as store:
    store.put('df', df, format='t')
    store.select('df', columns=['index'])

>>> lvl0    lvl1
>>>    0       y
>>>    1       z
```

It works but seems not being [documented](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.HDFStore.select.html#pandas.HDFStore.select).